# Stabilize touch events coordinates on touchmove

Tags: javascript, three.js, mousemove, touchmove

I'm working on a small application that allows users to draw freehand in 3d with three.js (the result is somewhat similar to Blender's [grease pencil](https://www.blender.org/features/grease-pencil/)). The application works in any browser but I'm struggling with my main target platform: the iPad with the Apple pencil.

Compared to a mouse, the Apple pencil fires a very high amount of touchmove events and that causes my lines to be "jagged" in some scenarios, especially when the line is drawn slowly.

Here's a [jsfiddle that shows the functionality](https://jsfiddle.net/jacopocolo/hen68xmz/show). The only thing I'm doing here is this:

```
//convert coordinate to three.js space
x = (x / window.innerWidth) * 2 - 1;
y = -(y / window.innerHeight) * 2 + 1;
var vNow = new THREE.Vector3(x, y, 0);

//unproject the coordinates based on the camera
vNow.unproject(camera);

//push a new line into the line geometry
line.geometry.vertices.push(vNow);

//re-render the line at every mousemove
setGeometry()
```

If you try it with a mouse, the result are pretty okay. But once you switch to Apple pencil… this is what I tend to get  the lines are mostly "jagged"

[image]

I tried many things, but nothing satisfied me yet.

- I tried generating curves from some or all of the coordinates and re-rendering the line on touchend but I do not like the effect and controlling the quality of the output is very difficult.
- I tried simplifying the line with [simplify.js](https://mourner.github.io/simplify-js) and while close to the desired result it produces inconsistent results.

So, I thought that instead of manipulating the output (the line) I could manipulate the input (the points) and stabilise them before drawing. What would be the best approach to "stabilize" mouse events, given an array of points? I googled left and right but did not find a good answer. Most solutions for drawing smooth curves are for the canvas, which is very different from 3d geometry.

Thanks!